# Can't edit form in html modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I have a problem with editing bootstrap forms. I set a default and a placeholder value via js. 
Now when the user is trying to change the value of the textfield, he can't.

Here is the code for my modal.

```
 getData(){
        //gets data from our api and replaces the values of the inputfields down below
    }

    render() {
        this.getData();
        return(
            <div class="modal fade" id="ChangePwModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="ChangePwModalModalLabel">Nutzer Details</h5>
                    <button type="button" id="PwModalClose" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form onSubmit={this.persDaten}>
                    <div className="input-group" id="inputgroop_changeemail">
                            <input type="text" className="form-control" id="neuesPw" name="dozMail" value= {getCookie("user")} required></input>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-row" id="changename">
                            <div class="col">
                            <input type="text" id="VornameDoz" class="form-control" name="dozVorname" placeholder="Vorname"></input>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col">
                            <input type="text" id="NachnameDoz" class="form-control" name="dozNachname" placeholder="Nachname"></input>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                        <button className="btn btn-danger d-flex justify-content-center" type="submit" id="modalbuttonsredpd"> 
                            Pesönliche Daten ändern
                        </button>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Abbrechen</button>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        );
    }
};

export default ChangePwModal;
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I already tried to copy other modals i use on that site to test, but same problem

Comment: can you put your code in a codesandbox or jsfiddle? so we can better understand what you are trying to say?

Comment: With *can't edit* you mean: can't click on it or can't enter any text?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier I updated the question hope this is clearer now.

Comment: When I edit the text inside the textfield, it gets instandly replaced whith the value from getData();

Comment: are you by chance opening a modal on top of another modal? I ran into that problem and the result was that tex fields became read-only. not exactly sure why.

Comment: My guess is that somewhere here... there is an onChange Event... which is triggering the change of state when something changes the textfield... With the way react works, if you change the state, it will causes a RERENDER ... which means that it will call the render() function again... as well as the "getData()" which will change the textfield again to what it was originally was.

My recommendation is to put `this.getData();` NOT IN THE `render()` function, but rather, put it in the `componentDidMount()` function

Comment: @Rick No, there is only one modal on this site.

Comment: @Zirc Thanks, that seems logic. I will try that.

Comment: @Zirc That worked! Thank you!

Comment: yey, glad It worked. I'll just put my comment as the answer so we could close this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that somewhere here... there is an `onChange` Event... which is triggering the change of state when something changes the textfield... With the way react works, if you change the state, it will causes a RERENDER ... which means that it will call the `render()` function again... as well as the `"getData()"` which will change the textfield again to what it was originally was. My recommendation is to put `this.getData();` NOT IN THE `render()` function, but rather, put it in the `componentDidMount()`